# Displaying picture and using two .html files in one website express and node.js

Tags: node.js, express, jsdom

Hey I need to create a relatively easy forum with express.js, body-parser and jsdom. I have got the site
running and I localhost does show me a website, but one of the images does not display itself and the other html file that should be added together with the one that is already there is not doing that.

[Picture of how my site looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmd00.png)

[Image of how the second html file looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO9xf.png)

My current code;

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jsDOM = require('jsdom');
const fs = require('fs');

let app = express();

app.listen(81, function() {
     console.log('Server is running on port 81!');

});
// first middleware with next()
app.use( function(request, response, next) {
    console.log(request.method, request.url);
    next();
});

// two middleware to one from express and one from  body-parser
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/Project-1')); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/write.html')

});
```

The image that does not display itself is a .svg image. 
Code I belive I need to add somewhere but I am not sure exactly where or how I should add it to my code.

// What should happen with a Post-call on /..

```
app.post('/', function( request, response) {

let htmlCode = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/static/html/index.html');
let serverDom = new jsDOM.JSDOM(htmlCode);
let bodyNodeRef = serverDom.window.document.querySelector('body');
```

And I Also believe that I need to tell the server what I am sending to it when it comes to the svg and other type of information and pictures.

```
if(ext === 'html') {
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                }

                if(ext === 'css') {
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css' });
                }

                if(ext === 'svg') {
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml' });
                }

                let content = fs.readFileSync(filnamn).toString();
                res.write(content);
                res.end();
```

I also have a blogPost.js code;

```
// Create a  js-array
var blogPosts = new Array();

// Put in the first post in the array
blogPosts.push({
    nickName: "Otto Kaski",
    msgSubject: "..........!",
    timeStamp: '1939-02-18',
    msgBody: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean feugiat faucibus sem, i.`
});

//Export the array for import in another file.
module.exports = { 'blogPosts': blogPosts };
```

Comment: And your directory structure is? (Which files go where?)

Comment: All my files (app.js, blogposts.js, index.html, write.html, package.json and package-lock.json and a folder called public is in the same folder called project1) In the public folder has a image folder that has a .svg picture that I cant get it to display itself ( in the first html image)

Comment: So everything is in /project-1 except the image, which is in /project-1/public/image? Then what is /static/html?

Comment: ops, it is supposed to be /html, not static, I moved my html file out of static and I have my two html files in the same folder. The post-call one is a suggestion, its not in my code. I Am not sure how I am supposed to use and put something like that in my code.

Comment: There are two reasons why your pix is not showing up... Either they are in the wrong path for the server to access them... or your server is NOT serving them (no route to them). Check the 2nd one first. Can you access the pix directly by entering its path into the browser? (Obviously not)   So, trace it. Which line in server is supposed to 'serve' the pix? How do you know it is reading from the right directory? Check it with console.log() commands of the variables.

Comment: I have a questions about the other problem I have, which is how I should make it so that index.html and write.html is displayed on the same website. Do you know how I can do that?